# What is the problem with zooming the window causing the rectangle to disappear?

Tags: c#, wpf

When scaling the window with wpf, Part of the rectangle has disappeared

[image: image.gif]

How should I make the window display rectangles properly when zooming?

```
<Grid Background="Azure">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid01" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Background="AliceBlue">
        <Image x:Name="ShowImage"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="myRectangle"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

My backend code

```
myRectangle.Fill = null;
myRectangle.Stroke = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red);
myRectangle.StrokeThickness = 3;
myRectangle.Width = nowWidth;
myRectangle.Height = nowHeight;
myRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(nowX, nowY - nowWidth / 2, 0, 0);
System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform rotateTransform = new(angle);
myRectangle.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
myRectangle.RenderTransformOrigin = new System.Windows.Point(0, 0);//渲染动画的起点-取值范围0-1
```

Comment: please have my  upvote for the repuation you need :)

Comment: It seems a bit strange that your view is a picture rather than controls.  You then draw a rectangle on top in order to highlight text in the picture.   You've considered using controls and a red border round a textblock?
You could draw your rectangle onto the picture and stretch it to fill the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wrap it all in a viewbox you the two controls wil scale with each other:

```
                <Grid Background="Azure">
                    <Viewbox>                            
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid01" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="1920" Height="1080" Background="HotPink">
                            <Image x:Name="ShowImage"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="myRectangle" Height="100" Width="100" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="5" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: It works, but after setting the rectangle, the picture shrinks a bit, there is some white space in the upper and lower parts, I don't know what is going on

Comment: try and use different values for viewbox.stretch and see which matches your expectations